# ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'tuple'>

Tags: file, path, buffer, valueerror

im a beginner with python ad try to semiautomate the import to YNAB.

It works if i use "askopenfilename" and do each csv seperated, but i couldnt get it to work with askopenfilenames and inside a for item in loop.

Then i get the following error message: 
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type:

Enclosed the python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.filenames = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/", title="Select file",
                                           filetypes=(("csv files", "*.csv"), ("all files", "*.*")))
print(root.filenames)
for item in root.filenames:
    print(item)
from pandas.core.tools.numeric import to_numeric
df = pd.read_csv(root.filenames, sep=';', usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 encoding='utf-8', decimal=',')
df.columns = ['Date', 'Payee', 'Verwendungszweck', 'Buchungstext', 'Betrag']
df['Memo'] = df[['Buchungstext', 'Verwendungszweck']].apply(lambda x: ' -- '.join(x), axis=1)
Betrag = df.Betrag.astype(int)
df['Inflow'] = np.where(df.Betrag > 0, df.Betrag, "")
df['Outflow'] = np.where(df.Betrag < 0, df.Betrag * (-1), "")
path = (root.filenames.replace('Download_Finanzblick', 'Converted_YNAB')[:-4] + '-converted.csv')
print(path)
df.to_csv(path, sep=';', index=False,
          columns=['Date', 'Payee', 'Memo', 'Inflow', 'Outflow'], decimal='.')
next(item)
```

and the Error Message:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe"
>   "C:/Users/dangeph/Repository/Finanzblick YNAB/Testfile.py"
>   ('C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon
>   - Kopie.csv', 'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon
>   - Kopie-converted.csv', 'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon-converted.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DB.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DiBA.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DKB.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DKB-Visa.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Paypal.csv',
>   'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/VB.csv')
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon
>   - Kopie.csv C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon
>   - Kopie-converted.csv C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Amazon-converted.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DB.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DiBA.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DKB.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/DKB-Visa.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/Paypal.csv
>   C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_YY/VB.csv
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/dangeph/Repository/Finanzblick YNAB/Testfile.py", line 21,
>   in 
>       encoding='utf-8', decimal=',')   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 678, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 424, in _read
>       filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py",
>   line 218, in get_filepath_or_buffer
>       raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer))) ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type:
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I don't know pandas, but this line looks like you're trying to read all the files at once: `df = pd.read_csv(root.filenames, ...` since `root.filenames` contains (potentially) more than one filename.

Comment: from filedialog.askopenfilenames i get back a list: _('C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_XX/Amazon - Kopie.csv', 'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_XX/Amazon.csv', 'C:/Users/dangeph/Desktop/Favoriten/Privat/YNAB/Download_Finanzblick/2019_XX/DB.csv')_ now i have to got through the list and convert each item (csv file) to another csv file. i tried with `i=0    while i < len(root.filenames):` and `for i in range(len(root.filenames)):` but i couldnt get it to work ;-(((